# How to increment a value in state item?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a view where I display all items, I want to increase the quantity of each item by clicking add button. I am having issues to set this up - here is what I've came up so far with.

```
  items: [{ 
      id: 1,
      name: "Car",
      quantity: 1
    },
    { 
      id: 2,
      name: "Car2",
      quantity: 1
    },
]
```

Mutation which I struggle with -> How do I target a specific item in array here?

```
increment(state) {
      state.items.quantity++
    }
```

html

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
<div>
{{item.name}}
{{item.quantity}}
<button @click="add()">+</button>
</div>
```

method in html

```
  add() {
      this.store.commit("increment")
    }
```

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: You didnt pass any item to ur add function and after increments mutation?

Comment: Your increment mutation logic doesnt make sense. Check it plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the id to the method and on to the mutation:

```html
<button @click="add(item.id)">+</button>
```

```js
add(id) {
   this.$store.commit("increment", id)
}
```

Prepare your mutation to receive the id and then find and increment the quantity

```js
increment(state, id) {
  const item = state.items.find(i => i.id === id);
  item.quantity++;
}
```